# Need approaches to split up SQL Server database for archival and reporting

Tags: sql-server, database, merge, replication, archive

I could use some help.  I have a 750 gb production database.  (Yeah, yeah, this issue might have been tackled sooner, but it's above my pay grade)  The database encompasses data from over several years of time.

The current requirement is to

1. MOVE (not just copy) older data to a separate archive database to increase performance in production. I.e. the rows will be **deleted** from production permanently.  This will be done periodically - I'm suggesting once monthly, on a rolling basis.  I don't know right away if the archive db will be on a different server - it may or may not.
2. Fashion a reporting environment such that it contains the **union** of the archive and production databases.  The catch is that the part comprised of production data must be updated at least once daily.  This environment will probably not be on the production server (but I could be wrong!)

For purposes of this question, let's assume the schemas are the same everywhere :)  All tables have a single primary key - an INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1).  We do have the ability to make snapshot copies of production via a SAN.  The primary keys must be preserved.

> What's Been Considered So Far

- We've considered replication and log shipping but neither will suffice to make the reporting database a union of the production and archive databases.
- We've considered partitioned views, but the primary key is an IDENTITY and accordingly won't work :(
- We've considered partitioning but I'm not in favor of a daily ETL that will require hundreds of gigs of I/O (we can't utilize the SAN snapshot with that approach).
- Lastly, I am considering a custom application approach that would emulate some of what SQL Server replication accomplishes, but with functionality more specific than what's in-the-box.  I *really* want to avoid doing something very custom.

What am I missing here?  This can't be a unique need.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? i.e. why is a 750GB database a problem?

Comment: Performance is starting to deteriorate, for one.  The client application inserts millions of rows per week.  It's been running that way now for a few years.  We can't limit the number of inserted rows - that's just the nature of the business.

Comment: @codenoire I have some ideas on this, but they involve our commercial technology, so not appropriate for a stackoverflow answer. You can email me if you would like to know more about it, my email is in my profile.

Comment: I guess you must have come up with some solution by now. It will be great if you could add an answer here describing what you finally did and how well it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

As @adriamn is asking, I have the same question.

You have one large table with tons of rows which does not scale for your purpose, e.g. because of locking, indexes etc.?

As it seems that historical data are read-only, you can easily cut them into different tables, e.g. by month, it does not matter. The point is that you can move these read-only data to different server, scale them using read-only replicas and so on.

Important thing is that you divide the data during the runtime to different tables and there is no single point of failure (or contention) in the database schema point of view.

Comment: That's an approach.  But the problem is that within the reporting environment that's being set up, we have some canned reports and then there is some functionality for ad hoc reporting.  It will compound the already-existing challenges for the user base if we start chopping up tables by date ranges.